# Is it common for an ISP to block outbound FTP (port 21)?

Tags: web-services, security

I have a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application and, as you know, the process of connecting to [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) (port 21) using [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) is relatively easy, but I am unable to connect. I think it's an [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) issue, because the last time I logged in was like six months ago, and it all worked fine. I have also turned off all firewalls, but same thing happens. I can't even do it through a web browser. Is it common for us ISPs to block outbound connections?

I am using [Verizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verizon_Communications).

Comment: Did you try to contact ISP support first?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking outgoing SMTP is quite common.

I haven't heard of any major ISP blocking FTP, but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen. It seems unlikely though.

More likely is that you are running behind a NAT system and need to use `PASV` to turn on [passive mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#NAT_and_firewall_traversal). If both server *and* client are behind NAT gateways, it is probably too much work to get FTP working to justify continuing to use it.

Might I suggest that now would be a good time to migrate to [`SFTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)? It is a much nicer protocol in many respects: there is a standard filename display (rather than just using whatever the `ls(1)` or `DIR` command output looks like), it does not require active vs passive silliness, and it does not require ascii vs binmode silliness.